# A bar is disappeared in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

After I upgrade intelliJ community version to the latest, one of bar ( don't know what it's called ) has been disappeared.

In old version, there is a long blue bar right above the menu bar which contains File, Edit, View, etc like below.
[image: Old version]

But in new version, the long blue bar right above the menu bar is disappeared. I checked setting but couldn't find how to get it back.
Does anyone know how to show the blue bar?

[image: new version]

Answer (score 2):

It's a new feature called "Borderless UI", to turn it off try this advice: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-219212#focus=streamItem-27-3615325.0-0